# Which Android emulators can co-exists on single machine?

Tags: adb, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

Which emulators can co-exists on single Windows machine and be used **simultaneously** for app development (adb support)? I'm using Genymotion which seems to work on bare system; AVD x86_64 requires Intel HAXM driver; how about Microsoft emulator from Visual Studio 2015? Did anyone tried it already?

EDIT: question was clarified to emphase the simultaneous work on one machine - virtualization issues are main topic, not CPU/RAM usage

Answer (score 1):

You can use as many emulators on the same machine as you want, simultaneously, at the same time, there's no actual limit, as long as you have sufficient RAM in your computer to handle that many emulators. When you want to debug an app you just choose whichever emulator you need.

Comment: I believe this is not true, as virtualization environments are mutually exclusive. Therefore I believe Microsoft emulator (Hyper-V) and Genymotion (VirtualBox) cannot run at the same time, but I ask for actual experience.

Comment: Actually i want to clarify that comment i just made. They are not mutually exclusive i.e. they do not prevent the other from running concurrently. There are not many programs out there that refuse to run concurrently with other similar programs. If you know of any I would like to know because this is news to me. So i repeat, as long as you have enough RAM you can run as much as you want. This is the whole point of a modern multitasking operating system. This isn't 1994.

Comment: @tomash This answer is correct, but you really have to be careful about RAM usage. I could open 2 AVD emulators, but that doesn't mean both will run flawlessly, given running 1 emulator is already a heavy task on my laptop.

Comment: RAM usage is not really in the scope of this question. I think it should be obvious to any Android programmer that they need a LOT of RAM to run Android emulators.

Comment: Question was edited - "simultaneously" translates to "without reboot required to switch virtualization host"

Comment: You can use them simultaneously, without rebooting, as long as you have sufficient RAM. Have you even tried using 2 emulators and it doesn't work? Because you don't seem to understand that it is not only possible, but this is why multitasking operating systems are a thing. Just open 2 virtualization hosts (or however many you need) and see what happens, because I think once you see it in practice you will understand what I am telling you makes sense.